# Ubuntu 16.04 installation failure without error message or crash on Acer Aspire v5 591g

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb, acer

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire v5 591g laptop. The specs I know for this model are:

> Intel core i7-6700HQ @ 2.6 ghz
>
> NVIDIA Geforce GTX 950m
>
> 8 GB DDR4 memory
>
> 128 GB Kingston SSD
>
> 1 TB Toshiba HHD
>
> Preinstalled with Windows 10 Home

I wasn't able to find anything more specific or information about the other hardware.

I attempted to install Ubuntu 16.04 via a bootable usb I created using the information at this [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on the Ubuntu homepage. The usb was created under Windows 7 on an 8 GB USB 2.0 flash drive. In order to use it, I disabled secureboot in the BIOS and changed the boot order such that USB drives had precedence. I was required to make a master password for the BIOS, that I cannot remove.

The installation was "successful", but would not boot.

Prior to the installation, I selected the option to erase Windows 10 from the SSD and replace it with Ubuntu 16.04. At various points the "continue" button prior to installation was grayed out for no given reason, such as when I selected "install third party software", which blanked out the "continue" button the next page for all installation options. Additionally, the name I wanted to give the laptop wasn't allowed as it "already existed on the network" when I know it did not. It would appear that anything that was not the default option was met with a grayed out "continue" button.

During the installation, everything seemed to be working fine, though it was pretty fast; less than 10 minutes. No errors were thrown and the installation completed, and prompted me to restart the laptop. On doing so, it booted back into the flash drive, showing the boot options for it. I powered off the laptop, removed the drive, and on reboot was informed there was bootable media.

On a second installation attempt, the same thing happened; "continue" buttons were grayed out, albeit on different pages, no error was thrown during the installation, and upon rebooting (again booting into the flash drive and powering down) I was again informed there was no bootable media. Additionally: during the second installation, one of the options was "install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Ubuntu 16.04", suggesting that the files were at the very least present on the SSD.

I'm fairly new to Linux, and have no idea where to go from here.

EDIT:

Some additional information:

here is the pastebin output of running boot-repair on the usb.

http://paste2.org/xKcw4Y47

This is the second time I have run boot repair, and neither time worked. The laptop boots to a screen saying that the boot device is missing, and to please insert recovery media.

The only option present in the BIOS boot menu is the Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: Every Acer we have seen needs a UEFI supervisory password and then in UEFI drill down in ESP -  efi system partition to set "trust" on grub2's .efi boot files. Some older threads mention downgrading UEFI (may be older systems also) but newer threads say newest UEFI from Acer works, best to make sure you have newest UEFI. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: You have a Skylake PC, and for my Skylake PC, I used [Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/), because somehow, it just worked. The other versions, `14.04` all the way to `14.04.4` and `16.04` didn't work. The installer would just disppear, and I thought it was a new way of installing. I did have to add `nouveau.modeset=0` in the startup options for it to work. Do mention if it does or doesn't work.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for the link - I was able to get the BIOS to recognize grub2 as a boot option, and the computer now boots to that. the newest Acer UEFI does indeed appear to work.